# Bootstrap assign spans to custom CSS id/class?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

How would I create a CSS ID #sidebar that is equal to span4? I mean I could do `<div id="sidebar" class="span4">`, but I would prefer to abstract that into #sidebar  by not typing span4 and not have to specify width dimensions manually in #sidebar either.

Is that possible with just plain CSS?

**Edit**: Found a great article on this issue: [Please stop embedding Bootstrap classes in your HTML](http://ruby.bvision.com/blog/please-stop-embedding-bootstrap-classes-in-your-html)

Comment: you mean to use a default width value ? if so, use `width:auto` on your `#sidebar`

Comment: No, it is not possible with pure CSS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it is not possible using only css.

Another solution is to make a custom build of bootstrap. You can add your a custom `less` style and build the bootstrap css from it. 
ex

```
#sidebar {
    .span4;
}
```

What you need to do is to
1. Clone the bootstrap repository
2. Add a `custom.less` files under `less` directory
3. Add `custom.less` file at the bottom of `bootstrap.less` file
4. Compile the `bootstrap.less` file with a tool like [Cruch!](http://crunchapp.net/)
5. Instead of the default `bootstrap.css` file use the custom file